# Как можно диагностировать проблему с Cumulative Layout Shift на сайте?

Tags: javascript, css3, веб-программирование, frontend, seo

Подскажите, как найти элемент с большим CLS?

Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) - один из показателей страниц сайта, на который смотрит Google.

В новых версиях хрома уже есть инструмент для диагностики и нахождения CLS. С помощью этого инструмента я нашел сдвиги и их устранил. Сейчас, когда запускаю pagespeed insights, он мне показывает что у меня CLS = 0. Эти изменения я сделал около 1-2 месяца назад и все страницы в **Google search console** в разделе **Основные интернет-показатели** вышли из красной зоны в зеленую.

Но буквально неделю-две они снова оказались в красной зоне... При этом pagespeed insights показывает, что у меня CLS = 0, но у 24% посетителей снова оно больше чем 0,24....  (Смотрите на картинке)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как это можно диагностировать?**

я уже менял в гугл хроме настройки размеров экрана, скорость загрузки, но толку нет....

пример теста: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fagrarii-razom.com.ua%2Fogoloshennia%2Fprodam-preparat-yaros-id1526&tab=desktop&hl=ru

Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы и комментарии!

Comment: https://web.dev/vitals/ и здесь https://web.dev/cls/

Comment: @outoftime А могут ли на эту статистику влиять, например если сайт посещают в 60-90% случаев люди пользующиеся интернетом 1 мегабит или 0,1 мегабит? Такое бывает, например если в основном заходят с мобилки, из учебных заведений, экономят на интернете и т п.?

Comment: Я с 2009 года с фронтендом не связан. Иногда поверхностно изучаю новшества. "Unexpected movement of page content usually happens because resources are loaded asynchronously or DOM elements get dynamically added to the page above existing content. The culprit might be an image or video with unknown dimensions, a font that renders larger or smaller than its fallback, or a third-party ad or widget that dynamically resizes itself."

Comment: Я проверял также и мобильную версию и там также для меня показывает смещение равно 0. Также и ограничивал скорость в эмуляторе гугл хрома, и также результат там был хорошим....

Comment: Также интересным является тот факт, что после того, как я исправил эту проблему на сайте и мне начало показывать 0, в течении почти 2-х меяцев этой проблемы не было у всех пользователей.... и сайт отвечал всем показателям.... а теперь скорее всего у них появилась, а мне показывает что всё хорошо...